# Replacing a Date Range BETWEEN clause using single Join column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-modeling, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

Database: Snowflake

I have a slowly changing Fact (yes, that's correct, fact not Dimension) that uses `EFFECTIVE_TS` and `EXPIRATION_TS` for the periodicity.

The Query uses `<input_date> BETWEEN EFFECTIVE_TS and EXPIRATION_TS` to get a Fact row. This has proved to be slow and before getting into clustering of table, I was wondering if I could have another generated column , call it `GENERATED_COL`,  generated out of `EFFECTIVE_TS` and `EXPIRATION_TS` with some magical logic such that instead of doing `<input_date> BETWEEN EFFECTIVE_TS and EXPIRATION_TS` I can do `Magical conversion(<input_date>) = GENERATED_COL`.

In other words, replacing a Date range with a single join column, if you have done this, please share , as we are facing challenges with between clause
(Due to the usecase, volume and slowly changing nature, the Fact has to be a
slowly changing timespan fact instead of a tranasaction or daily snapshot fact)

Thanks
Sunny

Answer (score 0):

instead of "replacing the BETWEEN" you should do "both" aka, use the EQUI-JOIN to chunking/block/batch the data, which is faster, and then do the fine grain on the smaller set of results.

here is a [45x speed up article from 2016](https://simeonpilgrim.com/blog/2016/08/02/snowflake-data-warehouse-date-range-based-joins-45x-speedup/) and a more data driven modern version of it but now offering [300x speed-up](https://select.dev/posts/snowflake-range-join-optimization). The speed-up themselves appear to have improved..

Comment: Thank you Simon. I will certainly go through the link materials and respond back in this forum